# Problem to call https request on iOS and Android

Tags: codenameone

I have a https request for getting data from an api server outside by the code below.

```
            ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(){
            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                retval[0] = false;
                return;
            }
        };
        req.setUrl(invUrl);
        req.setPost(true);
        req.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.addArgument("Param1","3.10");



        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
        int code = req.getResponseCode();
        String message = req.getResponseErrorMessage();
        if (retval[0]==false){
            return null;
        }
        byte[] data = req.getResponseData();
        if (data == null) {
            //throw new IOException(UIManager.getInstance().localize("!network_error", ""));
        }
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Map<String, Object> response = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "UTF-8"));
```

If I run the code on a simulator, the request always gets a successful response (99% successful).
If I run the code on Android, the request always fails to get a response with errors. (39% succesful).

Codes don't have issues on Android devices

```
            ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(){
            protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                os.write(JStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                retval[0] = false;
                return;
            }
        };
        req.setFailSilently(IS_FAIL_SILENT);
        req.setSilentRetryCount(RETRY_COUNT);
        req.setUrl(url.concat("....................."));
        req.setPost(true);
        req.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: The response code means the server sent back an error code. What's the code number? Use that to see what the server complained about. If it's in the 5xx range it's a server error. If it's in the 4xx range it's a problem in request formation which is often described in the error body. If it's in the 3xx range it means the URL moved to a new location. My bet is on the 4xx range so you will need to read the response text and see what it says there.

Comment: The response code is 0 without any error message. 
I got the error message through req.getResponseErrorMessage()

Comment: Zero would mean the response didn't initialize, that's weird. Do you see something printed in logcat on Android? I'm assuming this is an HTTPS URL as the title suggests and not an HTTP URL. Also verify that the certificate is valid for mobile devices as a self signed certificate won't work.

Comment: Yes, this is an HTTPS URL and not a self-signed certificate. This is a weird issue. The request failure is only in mobile but not in the simulator and the requests do not always fail in mobile(39% successful).

Comment: If it's sometimes successful this probably means there's a networking issue. I'm guessing the server is only accessible via a specific network and blocked in another. E.g. if you're connected to WIFI it will work but fail on cell network. Try connecting to your phone as a hotspot and then try to reproduce the problem in the simulator.

Comment: The simulator has API calls to the server through my phone as a hotspot the success rate is 100%. I have the same API calls to the server on my phone directly, the success rate is 35%. So Weird.

Comment: Try removing the silent retry and fail silently lines. Then try to reproduce the problem with a tethered phone. You might have better luck getting a decent error in that case.

Comment: It shows Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to api....... in my phone. But this exception won't be produced in the simulator and iOS. The simulator and iPhone connect to the server through my phone as the hotspot. My phone is Android.. Sorry, this issue is only on Android.

Comment: If this is only on Android maybe it has a bad wifi setting that it keeps grabbing? E.g. a wifi network that requires sign-in that it keeps connecting to? Maybe it has a problematic VPN?

Did you try other Android devices?

Comment: Yes, I tried other Android devices. I tried three Android devices, and all of them have this issue. The simulator and iPhone connect to the server through my Android devices as the hotspot. They don't have this issue. I don't use VPN. Is it possible on the problem of the Android library for the HTTPS request?

I have other https requests on Android devices without this issue. Please refer to the question.

The only difference on the codes is
Codes have issue: req.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Code without issue: req.setContentType("application/json");

Comment: It's not just that. You also submit a custom body with `buildRequestBody`. When you say failure is this to a server that's under your control? If so can you see if the request arrives there and what happens to it? I wouldn't want to go into wireshark debugging as this is a serious pain.
In the actual code do you submit different values as arguments? That might be the reason for the variation, maybe a specific argument value is triggering a failure?